# NMR splitting of protons in a ring

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I was presented with the following compound and asked to comment on the splitting of the proton $\ce{H_a}$ in $\ce{^1H}$ NMR.

[image: Molecule of concern]

The question presented today was:

> What is the chemical shift (below) and splitting pattern for $\ce{H_a}$ up to and
>   including $\ce{^4J}$?

I relabelled the molecule as shown:

[image: Molecule of concern relabelled]

but I was left stuck here. I know that $\ce{H_a}$ will be split by $\ce{H_d}$ and $\ce{H_e}$ to give a doublet of doublets (dd) but I was wondering, since the molecule is asymmetric. Now

*are the protons $\ce{H_c}$ and $\ce{H_d}$ chemically equivalent but magnetically inequivalent*

to yield the final splitting pattern as dddd?

Comment: And I find the wording of the question by your teacher a bit weird.The interesting point is wether a 4J coupling is large enough to become *observable*!

Comment: @Karl that was how the question was worded to me! I was just wondering if Hb and Hc are magnetically inequivalent, so they split the Ha signal with two different coupling constants?

Comment: @Karl done. I've shortened the question down to grasp the main point and clarified any grammatical errors.

Comment: Cool. ;) Ahem, a hint: you notice the methyl group at the bottom. I contains a lot of *electrons*. How do Hb and Hc feel about that?

Comment: @Karl Hb would feel a stronger magnetic field strength of the methyl then Hc as the methyl group and Hb are in the same plane so they would be at different chemical shifts as a result - That's what I would say is my answer to your question. Is that right?

Comment: I wouldn´t bet on which one is high/lowfield, but yes, they are certainly chemically inequivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two protons Hb and Hc are also *chemically* inequivalent, because they have a different chemical environment with the methyl group, i.e. they don´t have the same chemical shift.

In a chiral molecule, the protons in a methylene group are rarely really chemically equivalent. There is usually a preferred orientation.